# Is it possible to add or set DocVariable in Word document using Office.js API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, docvariable

I have Word documents with fields like `{ DOCVARIABLE "508" }`.  Can I use Office.js API to add or set document variables ?

Comment: As far as I know, the Office JS API has not facility for working with Word fields, because they aren't supported in Word On-line. There are a couple of requests on UserVoice (in the Office Developer section) for creating fields. FWIW Document `Variables` (and thus the `DocVariable` field) are older technology. For similar functionality you might want to research Content Controls linked to a Custom XML Part. The Office JS APIs support both, I believe.